# JQuery event selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selector

Say i have 10 small images that i want to use as tooltips.
Im assinging them all the same class, '.helper'

Im selecting helper, then calling

```
mouseenter(function() { $(".helper").stop(false,true).fadeIn(); })
```

I then want a div to popup, containing some text. This works fine if there's only one tooltip on the page, but as soon as there is more than one, whenever i hover over one, they all appear at the same time.

Have i got something fundamentally wrong?

Comments appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` as the selector inside instead of the `.helper` selector again:

```
$('.helper').mouseenter(function() {
    // "this" now refers to the image that is being hovered...
    $(this).stop(false, true).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering what the problem was, it was that when you called

```
 $(".helper")
```

within your function, you were getting all the elements with class helper, in stead of just the single element you wanted.

Comment: Any the only solution is to use 'this' ?

Comment: Yeah, what $(".helper") does is get you all elements with that class.  When you do .each(fn), it cycles through each element in the set returned by $(".helper") and sets each one as "this" in the fn.